# Create Horizontal List of Vertical Table Views

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm trying to create a view that will list different events on a per-day basis. In the header of the event table will be the date, and the rows of the table will be all the events on that date. Also in the header will be "previous" and "next" buttons, and clicking them will scroll left or right, displaying that day's new set of events.

[image: horizontal list of vertical tables]

What's the best way to approach this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i were you, i'd just use an `UITableView` and i'd create a custom header using   `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:`, create two `UIButton` and selector methods, once you click on one of the `UIButton` in the header section, you just need to reload data.

Comment: That's a perfectly reasonable idea, I was having a serious brain-fart.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd approach it, including the requested scrolling transition:   1) Size the view controller's view to be 2x the width of the screen.   2) Have two table view properties in the controller, the "currentTable" and the "nextTable", as children of the parent 2x-width view.   3) To transition, set (without animation) the frame origin of the "nextTable" to either the left (negative X coord value) or to the right of the "currentTable", and load its contents.  Then run an animation on the parent view X coordinate to either the left or the right.  After the animation finishes, set (again without animation so that the changes are not visible) the X coord of the parent view back to 0, and set the X coord of the currentTable to 0.   This way you can have endless transitions left and right with only two tableViews and a double-width parent view.

edit: and don't forget to swap the values of "currentTable" and "nextTable" after the transition.